# Gulp/Node: file content stream filter with isStream=true

Tags: node.js, stream, gulp

I haven't found any example online on how to handle `isStream` mode manually. All I could find is [prefixing/appending text and letting `through()` handle the actual streaming](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/dealing-with-streams.md):

```js
if (file.isStream()) {
    var stream = through();
    stream.write(prefixText);
    file.contents = file.contents.pipe(streamer);
}
```

I want to filter the file content through `encodeURI()`, though. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```js
if (file.isStream()) {
  var
    encoding = 'utf8',
    contents = [];

  function write (chunk, enc, done) {
    contents.push(chunk);
    done();
  }

  function end (done) {
    // Concat stored buffers and convert to string.
    contents = Buffer.concat(contents).toString(encoding);
    // encodeURI() string.
    contents = encodeURI(contents);
    // Make new buffer with output of encodeURI().
    contents = Buffer(contents, encoding);
    // Push new buffer.                
    this.push(contents);
    done();
  }

  // This assumes you want file.contents to be a stream in the end.
  file.contents = file.contents.pipe(through(write, end));
}
```